# Error display while get last inserted id postgresql php

Tags: php, database, postgresql, pgadmin

When i fire these query error generate in postgreSQL.

```
SELECT currval('tbl_social_links_id_seq');
```

[image]

Help me.

Comment: Is the column type 'serial'?

Comment: same error in my Postgre DB: it's normal

Comment: yes, column type is serial. still arising the error.